# Approximate the plastic number

Tags: code-golf, math, number

## The challenge

The [plastic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number) is a number related to the golden ratio, with many interesting mathematical properties. As such, there are many approaches that can be used to calculate the number.

In order to precisely specify the number for the purposes of this challenge, we'll use the following definition (although there are plenty of equivalent definitions, and you can use any definition you wish as long as it comes to the same number):

> The plastic number is a real number *ρ* such that *ρ*³=*ρ*+1.

Your challenge is to write a program or function which takes an integer *x* as input (with *x* > 1), and produces an approximation to *ρ* as output, such that the larger the value of *x* gets, the closer the output gets to *ρ* (with at most finitely many exceptions; staying at the same value counts as "closer" for this purpose), and for any positive number *δ*, there's some input *x* to your program that produces an output that's within *δ* of *ρ*.

## Clarifications

- If you're outputting via a method that inherently outputs strings (e.g. the standard output stream), you can format output either in decimal (e.g. `1.3247179572`), or as a ratio of two integers with a `/` character between them.
- If you're outputting as a value within your programming language (e.g. returning from a function), it must be of a fixed-point, floating-point, or rational type. (In particular, you can't use data types that store numbers symbolically, unless they're used only to hold the ratio of two integers. So if you're using Mathematica or a similar language, you'll need to include the extra code to actually generate the digits of the output.)
- Your answer must work in a hypothetical variant of your language in which integers can be arbitrarily large, and memory (including stack) is unlimited. You may *not* assume that floating-point arithmetic in your language is arbitrarily accurate, but must instead use its actual accuracy (meaning that outputting a floating-point number is only going to be possible in languages where the accuracy of floating-point numbers can be controlled at runtime).
- *x* can have any meaning you want (so long as increasing it gives more accurate outputs). I imagine that most submissions will have it control the number of digits of output to produce, or the number of iterations of the algorithm used by your program to converge on the plastic number, but other meanings are acceptable.

## Testcase

Here are the first few digits of the plastic number:

```
1.32471795724474602596090885
```

More digits are available [on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A060006).

## Victory condition

As usual for [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shorter is better, measured in bytes. However, feel free to post answers even if they don't win, so long as they add something (e.g. a different language, or a different algorithm) to the existing answers.

Comment: hmm, (cbrt(108+12*sqrt(69))+cbrt(108-12*sqrt(69)))/6 this seems like a good time to use `the Drake approximation': sqrt(69)=8.something http://bit.ly/2rCqedX ^_^

Comment: Can we also assume the recursion/stack depth is unlimited?

Comment: To clarify the second point, can we use arbitrary precision libraries (e.g. mpmath in Python)? They use an auxiliary data type, but do you count that as storing things "symbolically"?

Comment: @Batman: I believe `mpmath` works by storing a decimal expansion. That's not a symbolic data type, so it's fine.

Comment: @xnor: Yes, as usual on PPCG. I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: This is a great model for irrational number challenges. I really like the *x* parameter to control accuracy.

Comment: Is {{x -> 1.32471795724474602596090885}} a valid output format?

Comment: @Jenny_mathy: I'm not sure that we have a standard rule for that on PPCG; it might be worth asking on Meta (this is a situation where we'd expect the standard rules to be usable). I'm currently inclined towards no, but wouldn't much care if a meta discussion found otherwise.

Comment: Does *such that the larger the value of x gets, the closer the output gets to ρ* have to hold for *all* pairs of **x**?

Comment: @Dennis: Well, if it didn't, simply outputting all rationals in some order would be a valid solution; the rule's to prevent that. I don't think answers like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110132/62131) are what people would really expect from this sort of challenge.

Comment: Well, at the very least I'd expect answers to converge to **ρ**. Also, an "honest" solution could easily fail the test **x > y --> |ρx - ρ| > |ρy - ρ|** for a finite number of **(x, y)** pairs. If that isn't acceptable, I think this should be made more explicit in the spec.

Comment: @Dennis: OK, I've clarified the ambiguity by allowing finitely many exceptions (given that it's not very interesting to be forced to add a constant to *x* to jump past exceptions with low values).

Comment: Many answerers have fallen into the trap(?) of computing an x digit approximation to ρ, the problem being that there are probably infinitely many x such that an (x + 1)-digit approximation is no better than an x digit approximation. You should probably clarify whether you intended this to be allowed. If you don’t, replace “closer” with “strictly closer”; if you do, “at least as close”, or something. You could also consider the looser requirement that the sequence [converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition) to ρ, which would additionally allow xnor’s answer.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg: OK, that was a clear bug in the problem (with zero digits getting no closer). I've fixed it. As for converging, I'm rather torn on that; note that most of the current solutions that converge (but go backwards infinitely many times) can easily be fixed by using 2**x rather than just x.

Comment: @ais523 I'd favor just going with convergence because it's a standard definition rather than a custom-made one. It's what I'd expect for a challenge to approximate a value arbitrarily well.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
n=x=input()
while n**3/x/x<n+x:n+=1
print n,'/',x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8@2wjYzr6C0REOTqzwjMydVIU9Ly1i/Qr/CJk@7wipP29aQq6AoM69EIU9HXV9dp@L/f0MDEAAA)

The idea is to express the `ρ` with `ρ³=ρ+1` as a fraction `n/x` whose denominator `x` is the input accuracy parameter. We take `(n/x)³=n/x+1` and clear denominators to get `n³=x²(x+n)`.

Since the LHS increases in `n` faster than the RHS, we can approximate the equality point `n` as the smallest with `n³≥x²(x+n)`. The code counts up `n` until this is the case, starting at `x` which is smaller.

A small byte save is to divide both sides by `x²` to write `n³/x²≥x+n` (negated in the `while` condition). This is floor division in the code, but the fractional part lost is negligible.

A same-length alternative instead puts `x` as the numerator:

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes**

```python
n=x=input()
while x**3/n/n<n+x:n-=1
print x,'/',n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8@2wjYzr6C0REOTqzwjMydVoUJLy1g/Tz/PJk@7wipP19aQq6AoM69EoUJHXV9dJ@//f0MDIAAA)

Comment: Although this output converges to ρ (∀ε > 0 ∃x₀ ∀x ≥ x₀ |f(x) − ρ| < ε), it doesn’t satisfy “the larger the value of x gets, the closer the output gets to ρ (with at most finitely many exceptions)” (∃x₀ ∀x ≥ x₀ |f(x + 1) − ρ| < |f(x) − ρ|).

Comment: This problem can be fixed by using `2**input()` rather than just `input()`; then, each approximation will be as least as accurate as the one before.

Answer (score 10):

## Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
#^3-#-1&~Root~1~N~#&
```

Mathematica's builtin `Root` function gives the solutions to a polynomial equation `f[x] == 0`.

#### Explanation

```
#^3-#-1&~Root~1~N~#&
                   &  (* Function *)
#^3-#-1&              (* A pure-function polynomial, x^3-x-1 *)
        ~Root~1       (* Find the first root *)
               ~N~#   (* approximate to (input) digits *)
```

#### Sample I/O

```
In[1]:= f=#^3-#-1&~Root~1~N~#&;
        f[1]

Out[1]= 1.

In[2]:= f[9]

Out[2]= 1.32471796

In[3]:= f[100]

Out[3]= 1.324717957244746025960908854478097340734404056901733364534015050302827851245547594054699347981787280
```

Comment: PS: `Root[x^3-x-1,1]~N~#&` works fine (despite not telling it that `x` is a variable) for the same byte count.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg: I changed that rule because it was clearly broken. No valid answers were invalidated, but some answers (like this one) became valid.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 27 bytes

```
x/.Solve[x^3==x+1>2,x]~N~#&
```

*-1 byte from Martin*
*-2 bytes from ovs*

**input**

> [27]

**output**

> {1.32471795724474602596090885}

Comment: `Solve[x^3==x+1>2,x]~N~#&` for 24 bytes

Comment: The result of this is `{{x -> 1.32...}}` though. You might want to check with ais whether that's a valid output format.

Comment: ok.. all fixed i guess

Comment: It's still `{1.32...}` actually, but that format is probably less contentious.

Comment: @Martin what are the rules about this format?

Comment: I made the challenge a bit more general so that this would be valid, it wasn't meant to disallow "first x digits" solutions. So this is valid now, even though it wasn't before.

Answer (score 6):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>67</s> 60 (59+1) bytes

```
s,^,1/1/1 ,
:;s,(1*/(1*)/(1*).*)1$,\2\3/\1,
t
s,(/1*).*,\1,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WCdOx1AfCBV0uKysi3U0DLX0gVgTTOhpaRqq6MQYxRjrxxjqcJVwAeX1weI6QP7//4bI4F9@QUlmfl7xf11XAA)

+1 for the `-E` flag (ERE instead of BRE). Input and output are both unary: input 11111 for x=5 e.g. Output is a fraction of two unary numbers: the aforementioned 11111 input yields output 11111/1111 (5/4 in decimal).

Approximates the plastic number as a fraction between to consecutive elements of the [Padovan sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence).

Comment: FWIW you don't need a space after the `b` command, but you can make it shorter still by using the empty label (`:` and `b` with no argument). https://tio.run/#%23K05N@f@/WCdOx1AfCBV0uKysi3U0DLX0gVgTTOhpaRqq6MQYxRjrxxjqcOkbqugncQHV6IPldIBi//8bIoN/@QUlmfl5xf91XQE

Comment: Oh excellent. And I can save yet another 4 bytes by using `t` instead of `b`, so that's a pretty nice save. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 27 bytes

```
Nest[(1+#)^(1/3)&,1,#]~N~#&
```

Uses a truncated approximation of the nested cubic radical form **³√(1+³√(1+³√(1+...)))**. While the output will always have *x-1* decimal places, the result is actually less accurate than that, because the expression converges more slowly than one digit per iteration (*x* is also used as the number of nested radicals that are computed). For example *x = 100* gives

```
_________________________________________________________________________
1.324717957244746025960908854478097340734404056901733364534015050302827850993693624204577670741656151
```

where the overlined part is correct.

Comment: I was planning to write this algorithm in `dc`, but got stymied because it turns out that it doesn't have a cube root operation, and raising a number to the power ⅓ doesn't work either :-( At least you can always count on Mathematica to have appropriate builtins…

Comment: @ais523 There's actually `CubeRoot` but ain't nobody got bytes for that.

Answer (score 4):

## MATL (<strike>27</strike> 28 bytes)

```
7BG:"t@)y@Q)+h]tG3+)yG2+)/
```

My first solution (27 bytes)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39zJ3UqpxEGz0sFQW1M7I7bE3Vhbs9LdSFtT//9/Q7Ovefm6yYnJGakA)

It's certainly not optimal, I'm still getting used to MATL.

### Explanation:

I create a [Padovan sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence) up to input+3 then find the ratio of the last two numbers.

```
7B     % Turn 7 into binary to give 1 1 1 
G:"    % For k=1:input do...
t@)    % Existing sequence member k
y@1+)  % Existing sequence member k+1
+h     % Add them together and concatenate to the sequence array
]      % End loop
tG3+)  % Final sequence member
yG2+)  % Second last sequence member
/      % Divide to approximate ρ
```

### Proper fraction output <strike>(35 bytes)</strike> (28 bytes, @Sanchises):

However, the first solution doesn't fulfill the need for arbitrary precision being the floating point limit of default MATL settings. So rather than adding several bytes to extend this precision, it's simpler to take the proper fraction route and write a fraction of the final two integers in the (N-1)<sup>th</sup> and N<sup>th</sup> elements of the truncated Padovan sequence.

e.g "114/86"

<strike>7BG:"t@)y@1+)+h]tG3+)V'/'YcyG2+)VYc</strike>

```
7BG:"t@tQh)sh]tJ)V47hyJq)Vh&
```

Courtesy of user @Sanchises. :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39zJ3UqpxKEkMEOzOCO2xEszzMQ8o9KrUDMsQ@3/f0Ozr3n5usmJyRmpAA)

### Non-iterative evaluation:

Notably, my shortest code for [the 'exact' version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number) is (23 bytes):

```
1-1h69X^12**108+1I/^6/s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/31DXMMPMMiLO0EhLy9DAQtvQUz/OTL/4//@vefm6yYnJGakA)

...but doesn't give arbitrary precision. I wonder if anyone can adjust this to fulfill the rules (use the input etc) and still add less than 5 bytes? :P

Comment: `1+` can be shortened to `Q`.With that in mind, you can replace `@)y@1+)+` with just `@tQh)s`. Furthermore, you can use `J` to indicate the end of an array; and finally, MATL doesn't distinguish between normal arrays and character arrays, so you can replace `Yc` by `h` (you don't need the extra functionality of `Yc`). This gives just 28 bytes: `7BG:"t@tQh)sh]tJ)V47hyJq)Vh&` (notice the `&` to prevent superfluous output, and replacing `'/'` by 47).

Comment: Kudos for the `7B` though, much better than naively pushing `lllv`

Comment: Thank you Sanchises! :) I added your extensions into the main post with attribution of course. I'm actually more maths than comsci, so it's a bit over my head rn, but I will try to learn these tricks you've used over time. :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have an updated list of MATL functions? I am using the original paper and it seems that "&" and "J" have both changed in their use since then! :P http://bit.ly/2slXc40

Comment: Oh and yeah, the 7B trick is nice, I saw it used in some older MATL solutions on Padovan's here on PPCG, so can't take credit there. :)

Comment: @DrQuarius The latest version can always be found [in this GitHub link](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/blob/master/spec/MATL_spec.pdf)

Comment: @DrQuarius No, this behaviour is present in the rather old MATL spec I generally use. You should really check out Table 3. Not only does clipboard `J` by default contain `1j`, but the clipboard `L` also contains many useful indexing functions (note that `1j` equals `end` in MATL).

Comment: Also, don't worry, I'm an mechanical engineer. I think MATL(AB) has little use outside of a scientific environment, so I would guess that the majority of MATL(AB)/Octave golfers are from outside CS.

Comment: As for `&`, note that every MATL program implicitly has a `XD` appended to it. `&XD` is equivalent to `1$XD`, or 'only display one item of the stack', which conveniently discards all other contents on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
²×3’
*3Ḥ‘÷Ç
Ç¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9t///CssOXM@KAmQoqM@G4pOKAmMO3w4cKw4fCof///zU)

#### Algorithm

This uses rationals and Newton's method. Specifically, for input **x**, the first **x** iterations with starting value **x** are applied.

We're trying to find a specific root of the polynomial **p(t) = t³ - t - 1**. Newton's method achieves this by taking a starting value **t<sub>0</sub>** – sufficiently close to **ρ** – and recursively defining a sequence by
**t<sub>n+1</sub> = t<sub>n</sub> - p(t<sub>n</sub>) / p'(t<sub>n</sub>)**.

Since **p'(t) = 3t² -1**, we get
**t<sub>n+1</sub> = t<sub>n</sub> - (t<sub>n</sub>³ - t<sub>n</sub> - 1)/(3t<sub>n</sub>² - 1) = (3t<sub>n</sub>³ - t<sub>n</sub> - t<sub>n</sub>³ + t<sub>n</sub> + 1) / (3t<sub>n</sub>² - 1) = (2t<sub>n</sub>³ + 1) / (3t<sub>n</sub>² - 1)**.

Note that the initial approximation **x** gets progressively worse as **x** increases. While the output for **x = 3** is slightly less precise than the output for **x = 2**, since Newton's method converges quadratically to **ρ**, this shouldn't be an issue for large values of **x**.

#### How it works

```
Ç¡    Main link. Argument: x

Ç¡    Call the second helper link x times, which initial argument x.


*3Ḥ‘÷Ç  Second helper link. Argument: t

*3      Compute t³.
  Ḥ     Unhalve; yield 2t³.
   ‘    Increment; yield 2t³+1.
     Ç  Call the first helper link with argument t.
    ÷   Divide the left result by the right one.


²×3’    First helper link. Argument: t

²       Compute t².
 ×3     Compute 3t².
   ’    Decrement; yield 3t²-1.
```

Comment: Too bad you can't use ...`µ¡`...

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 50 bytes

```matlab
@(n)char(digits(n)*0+vpasolve(sym('r^3-r-1'))(1));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI08zOSOxSCMlMz2zpBjI0zLQLitILM7PKUvVKK7M1VAvijPWLdI1VNfU1DDU1LT@n6ZhqsmVpmFooPkfAA)

Defines an anonymous function, with`n` the desired number of digits of output.

This answer abuses that `digits` returns the current setting for the number of digits in variable precision arithmetic. This means we can just use it in an anonymous function without errors about 'Too many output arguments'.

Other than that, it's really straightforward: `vpasolve` is short for Variable-Precision Arithmetic Solve, with the precision set by the last call of `digits`. Since `vpa` is a Symbolic data type in Octave, which is banned per the spec, we just wrap the whole function in `char(...)` to get string output. Note that in `solve` and `vpasolve`, the `f==0` is implied, so `r^3==r+1` has been replaced by `r^3-r-1 (==0)`

Comment: I went and changed the question so that it doesn't disallow answers like this (it wasn't meant to).

Comment: @ais523 Thanks for the notification!

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/),  <s>44</s>  40 bytes

```
|(x,r=1)=x<1?r:~-x|big(2r^3+1)//(3r^2-1)
```

Uses rationals and Newton's method.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f@/RqNCp8jWUNO2wsbQvsiqTreiJikzXcOoKM5Y21BTX1/DuCjOSNdQ839afpFChUJmnoKGoZWhgSYXZ5GCrQJQN5BVUJSZV5KTp1Gko6Ck8KizQ0FJRyEtJz@xRKNIU5MrNS/lPwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 19 bytes

```apl
{{(⍺+⍵*÷3)*÷3}/⍵/1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG9qQMCjtgnGJv@rqzUe9e7SftS7VevwdmNNEFGrD@TpG9b@TwMqedTb96ir@VHvmke9Ww6tN37UNhGoOTjIGUiGeHgG/09TMORKUzACYmMgNgFiUyA2A2JDAwMDAA)

Uses the cube root approximation method, which very, very slowly creeps towards the value of the plastic number.

### Explanation

```apl
{{(⍺+⍵*÷3)*÷3}/⍵/1} ⍵ → input
               ⍵/1} replicate 1 ⍵ times
 {           }/     reduce by inner fn:
          *÷3       cube root of
     ⍵*÷3           cube root of right arg
   ⍺+               plus left arg
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 66 bytes

```rust
|n|{let mut i=(1,1,1);for _ in 0..n{i=(i.1,i.2,i.0+i.1)}(i.1,i.2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RUzLDsIgELzzFWtPbESk9ibBXzEmlmSTsjUVTpRvRzAxZg4zmdeW3rF6hvAglpiXOYK/epY0XfB066S6dHXn/ZuGFIGcHFUDWr9ucAdiMFpzbj7pUZFuI22OTWP5OViqFf1AcgrqOfMa0Hk5GbTitRHHhQ9yyOWcy6D@FStK/QA)

Uses the padovan sequence to approximate the plastic number. Returns a tupled `(num,denom)`. A readable version that works with arbitrary precision integers can be found [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20num%3A%3ABigUint%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20f%3Afn(i32)-%3E(BigUint%2CBigUint)%20%3D%20%7Cn%7C%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20i%3D(1u32.into()%2C1u32.into()%2C1u32.into())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20_%20in%200..n%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20tmp%20%3D%20%26i.0%2B%26i.1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20i%3D(i.1%2Ci.2%2Ctmp)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(i.1%2Ci.2)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20(num%2Cdenom)%20%3D%20f(900)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%2F%7B%7D%22%2Cnum%2Cdenom)%3B%0A%7D).

Answer (score 2):

## AWK, 34 bytes

```
{for(;$1^3>$1+1;)$1=($1+1)^(1/3)}1
```

Step by step:

```
{                  # $1 is the input (a positive integer)
for(;$1^3>$1+1;)   # as long as $1 cubed is bigger than the input plus one
  $1=($1+1)^(1/3)  # assigns $1 this new value: cube root of $1 plus one
}
1                  # prints $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMNaxTDO2E7FUNvQWlPF0FYDxNKM0zDUN9asNfz/34jLmMuUy9CAy8zEnMvS0NjQxMwcAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes

```
U[X3m¹/¹/¹X+›#X>U]X'/¹J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/NDrCOPfQTn0witB@1LBLOcIuNDZCHcj1@v/f0AAIAA)

---

Direct port of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126822/59376 by xnor.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
ＡＩθθＡθνＷ‹∕∕Ｘν³θθ⁺νθＡ⁺ν¹νＩ∕νθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DObG4RKNQU0ehUNOaCypWqKOQB@SVZ2TmpCpo2Gh45pW4ZJZlpqQisbS0NPJ0FIzBGiFYGyRQqKmpyaUABFCjwIKGmiADuQKKMvNKIBYizIHq@f/f0MjY/L9u2X/d4hwA) Link to verbose mode. Also I apparently messed up `Divide` and `IntDivide` :|
Uses the same method as the Python and JavaScript answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [NewStack](https://github.com/LyamBoylan/NewStack), 14 bytes

```
¹Fᵢ{E2x³⁺÷3x²⁻
```

#### Break down:

```
¹                Add arbitrary number 1 to the stack.
 Fᵢ{             Define for loop with a user's input amount of itterations.
    E            Define new edit for element 0 (element 0 being the 1 added. earlier).
     2x³⁺÷3x²⁻   update x to equal (2x^3+1)/(3x^2-1). (x = element 0).
```

#### How it works:

The formula (2x<sup>3</sup>+1)/(3x<sup>2</sup>-1) comes from the simplification of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for the equasion x<sup>3</sup>=x+1. You can find it [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20x-(x%5E3-x-1)%2F(3x%5E2-1)). Repeating this process an infinite amoune of times converges to the plastic number. It's rate of convergence is rather quick at around 2.6 decimals per iteration.

```
INPUT ITERATION >> VALUE
0 >> 1
1 >> 1.5
2 >> 1.3478260869565217
3 >> 1.325200398950907
4 >> 1.3247181739990537
5 >> 1.3247179572447898
6 >> 1.324717957244746    <- 16 decimal precision in 6 iterations!
...
100 >> 1.324717957244746
```

## Padovan sequence alternative, <strike>27</strike> <strike>25</strike> 17 bytes

```
¹Fᵢ{[ƨ2+ƨ3]ℲƤƨ/ƨ2
```

#### Break down:

```
¹                  Append first element of Padovan sequence.
 Fᵢ{       Ⅎ       Define for loop of user's input amount of iterations.
    [ƨ2+ƨ3]        Append sum second and third to last elements.
            Ƥƨ/ƨ2  Print ratio of last two elements.
```

-2 bytes by choosing better print strategy

-8 bytes by choosing better way to index stack

#### How it works:

As the [Padovan sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence) continues, the ratio of the last two elements converge to the plastic number.

```
INPUT ITERATION >> VALUE
0 >> 1
1 >> 2
...
10 >> 1.3157894736842106
...
89 >> 1.324717957244746    <- 16 decimal precision in 89 iterations
...
100> > 1.324717957244746
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```ruby
->x{n=1;n+=0.1**x while n**3-n<1;n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iOs/W0DpP29ZAz1BLq0KhPCMzJ1UhT0vLWDfPBihR@79AIS3aMJYLRBlBKGMIZRL7HwA)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 46 bytes

```
#(nth(iterate(fn[i](Math/pow(inc i)(/ 3)))1)%)
```

Uses the iterated cube-root formula. This is a bit more interesting but longer:

```
(def f #(apply comp(repeat %(fn[i](Math/pow(inc i)(/ 3))))))

((f 10)1)
1.3247179361449652
```

Comment: “You may _not_ assume that floating-point arithmetic in your language is arbitrarily accurate, but must instead use its actual accuracy (meaning that outputting a floating-point number is only going to be possible in languages where the accuracy of floating-point numbers can be controlled at runtime).”

Comment: Ooh I did not notice that, what a bummer. And implementing cubic root with BigDecimal seems quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 36 bytes

```
f=(x,n=x)=>n**3/x/x<n+x?f(x,++n):n/x
```

Works the same as the top python answer. No `console.log` was included because if you run `f(x)` in console it will be logged automatically.

```js
f=(x,n=x)=>n**3/x/x<n+x?f(x,++n):n/x
console.log(f(300))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 38+3 = 41 bytes

```
11\n;
?!\}2,:01{::::}**-+0(?$-{+{1-:}
```

Expects the input to be present on the stack at program start, so +3 bytes for the `-v` flag.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39AwJs@ay14xptZIx8rAsNoKCGq1tHS1DTTsVXSrtasNda1q////r1umYGoAAA)

Effectively performs a binary search to narrow in on the output value. Increasing `x` increases the number of iterations to perform.

*Edit: refactored calculation slightly to save 1 byte, previous version:*

```
11\n;
?!\}2,:0{::::}**$-1-0)?$-{+{1-:}
```

Answer (score 0):

## k, 27 bytes

```
{"/"/$1_|x({y,z,x+y}.)/3#1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pJX0lfxTC@pkKjulKnSqdCu7JWT1PfWNmwVl3R0MDg/38A) This assumes infinite integers (which, alas, is not true). It uses the [Padovan sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence).

Answer (score 0):

### [C#](https://tio.run/##tVI7b8IwEN75Fad0iE2DIaBOiKlSpUpQRaJqB8RgEhcsJXZlXyAVym9PnYRX6NwbPNx9j/tOju0g00pXVW6l2sLyx6LIpr045dZCdOyBK4scZQx7LRNYcKmIRePAqzVws7W0wbTIup61sjoV7NNIFHOpBImcmBN4y7ONMEQqZBE3VpCavRqtKaXThl3Wz61j6wN/@FDcm8ovIAXMZjCmcGnWZQTmRoEXDkNvepnsuYEEZnfKBQwgpGz5nUok/tCnXcLGEdr7MJdxLwyyd/2qcDImSR2ji44d@ho1WYW3gNNWbT72ok3GkXjHUTk8hqUXdCOQMfTd3XHHIn0gmwAmFB6vjbhu0A7D7bVspIkSh5ML8R/8oNlowYsPnubiiqJsLtQWd5QGXefJnbO7bt8lG/yT@/kf9Mqqqp5@AQ), 317 bytes

```
using m=System.Math;a=x=>{if(a==0)return "1/1";var d=a(x-1).Split('/');var b=int.Parse(d[0]);var c=int.Parse(d[1]);return string.Format("{0}/{1}",(2*m.Pow(b,3)+m.Pow(c,3)).ToString(new string('#',int.MaxValue.ToString().Length)),(3*m.Pow(b,2)*c-m.Pow(c,3)).ToString(new string('#',int.MaxValue.ToString().Length)));};
```

It returns the result as a fraction.

#### Explanation

It uses the Newton's method with x iterations for finding the root of the polynomial p^3-p-1=0. The formula is x_n=1-(f(x_(n-1)))/(f'(x_(n-1))), and x_0 is a starting point.

The polynomials derivative is 3p^2-1, and let's say x_(n-1)=b/c. Then, by using the above formula we get, that  x_n=(2 b^3+c^3)/(3 b^2 c-c^3). Let's also say, that we start from 1, this will happen, when x=2, because x>1, and is an integer.  Idented, and commented code:

```
using System;
string PlasticNumber(int x)
{
    if (x == 2) 
        return "1/1";                 

//If x=2, we return our starting value, but we need to return it as a fraction

    var d = PlasticNumber(x - 1).Split('/');
    var b = System.Convert.ToInt32(d[0]);
    var c = int.Parse(d[1]);

//We parse the previous value of the fraction, and put it into two variables

    return string.Format("{0}/{1}", 
        (2 * Math.Pow(b, 3) + Math.Pow(c, 3))
        .ToString(new string('#', int.MaxValue.ToString().Length)),
        (3 * Math.Pow(b, 2) * c - Math.Pow(c, 3))
        .ToString(new string('#', int.MaxValue.ToString().Length)));

//We return the result as a fraction, but it's important not to return it in
  scientific notation, because that will cause issues in the parsing process 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 21 bytes

```
:Prompt X //Prompt for input, 3 bytes
:While X  //While X, 3 bytes
:³√(1+Y→Y //Calculate cube root of 1+Y and store to Y, 7 bytes
:DS<(X,0  //Decrement X and skip next command (which doesn't do anything), 5 bytes
:End      //End While loop, 2 bytes
:Y        //Display Y, 1 byte
```

Uses this [recursive formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number#Recurrences).

Interestingly, hard-coding the number and rounding it gives the same byte-count:

## TI-BASIC, 21 bytes

```
:Prompt X    //Prompt for input, 3 bytes
:.5√(3       //Store √(3)/2 to Ans, 5 bytes
:Ansֿ¹cosh(3ֿ¹coshֿ¹(3Ans //Store the plastic number to Ans, 9 bytes
:round(Ans,X //Round the plastic number X decimal digits, 4 bytes
```

Uses this [trigonometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number#Trigonometry).

Comment: I don't think you can use TI-BASIC's floats here: `Your answer must work in a hypothetical variant of your language in which integers can be arbitrarily large, and memory (including stack) is unlimited. You may not assume that floating-point arithmetic in your language is arbitrarily accurate, but must instead use its actual accuracy (meaning that outputting a floating-point number is only going to be possible in languages where the accuracy of floating-point numbers can be controlled at runtime).`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 86 bytes

```php
for($p=[1,1,1];$i++<$argn;)$p[]=bcadd($p[$i],$p[$i-1]);echo bcdiv($p[$i+1],$p[$i],$i);
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/06b11e67f076ef77255504ca2566fedc36e1df4d)

Creates the [Padovan Spiral](https://oeis.org/A134816) and print the ratio of the last two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 96 bytes

```
h(n:NNI):Float==(n>1.E5=>-1;n:=n+1;j:=digits(n::PI);r:=solve(x^3-x=1,10.^-n);digits(j);rhs(r.1))
```

results

```
(31) -> [h(i) for i in 0..10]
   (31)
   [1.0, 1.3, 1.33, 1.325, 1.3247, 1.32472, 1.324718, 1.324718, 1.32471796,
    1.324717957, 1.3247179572]
                                                         Type: List Float
```

how you can see h(2) should be 1.32 and not 1.33 so there is some error in last digits

Then there would be this one of 110 bytes

```
g(n:NNI):Float==(n>1.E5=>-1;n:=n+1;j:=digits(n::PI);x:=sqrt(23./108);r:=(.5+x)^(1/3)+(.5-x)^(1/3);digits(j);r)
```

It use the formula for resolve equation of III grade of type x^3-3*p*x-2*q=0
in the case q^2-p^3>=0 that is m=sqrt(q^2-p^3) and x=(q+m)^(1/3)+(q-m)^(1/3)

In our case r^3-r-1=0 this can be written as r^3-3*(1/3)r-2*(1/2)=0 so p=1/3 q=1/2 m=1/4-1/27=23/108
x=(0.5+m)^(1/3)+(0.5-m)^(1/3)

this one that use Newton iteration with start point r=1

```
f(n:NNI):Float==(n>1.E5=>-1;n:=n+1;j:=digits(n::PI);e:=10^-n;r:=1.;repeat(v:=(r^3-r-1)/(3*r^2-1);abs(v)<e=>break;r:=r-v);digits(j);r)
```

it change in the function, digits value for obtain one obj of n+1 digits afther 
the float point. At end the digits() value is assigned back to preciding value.