# Find Index of Rational Number in Calkin-Wilf Sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

*[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15934/find-a-fractions-position-in-the-stern-brocot-tree)*

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree):

> In number theory, the Calkin–Wilf tree is a tree in which the vertices correspond one-to-one to the positive rational numbers. The tree is rooted at the number \$1\$, and any rational number expressed in simplest terms as the fraction \$\frac{a}{b}\$ has as its two children the numbers \$\frac{a}{a+b}\$ and \$\frac{a+b}{b}\$.
>
> [image: Calkin-Wilf tree]
>
> The Calkin–Wilf sequence is the sequence of rational numbers generated by a breadth-first traversal of the Calkin–Wilf tree,
> $$\frac11, \frac12, \frac21, \frac13, \frac32, \frac23, \frac31, \frac14, \frac43, \frac35, \frac52, \ldots$$

For this challenge, you are given a fraction found in the \$i\$th position of the Calkin-Wilf sequence, and must output \$i\$. You can start from either 0 or 1.

### Test cases

(Starting from 1.)

| \$a_i\$ | \$i\$ |
| --- | --- |
| \$\frac11\$ | \$1\$ |
| \$\frac13\$ | \$4\$ |
| \$\frac43\$ | \$9\$ |
| \$\frac34\$ | \$14\$ |
| \$\frac{53}{37}\$ | \$1081\$ |
| \$\frac{37}{53}\$ | \$1990\$ |

Standard loopholes are forbidden. Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code wins.

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

Expects a pair of integers `(p,q)` representing the fraction \$p/q\$.

```javascript
f=(p,q)=>p&&1+f(q+p-(q%p||p)*2,p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctBDkAwEEDRvXuQGYakSqy4S0MrRHSqYuXuZa22L/@v6lJ@PBY@y91OOgTTA5PDfuAsE4UBV3AJLuX7ZsxrYgyj3b3ddLXZGQwIEojJ12RkzY9JaiJrJckuLjtq3z88)

#### How?

This version is based on the nice recurrence formula found by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260482/58563):

$$\begin{align}f(0)&=0\\f(x)&=1+f(2\lceil1/x\rceil-1-1/x)\end{align}$$

It was modified to work with two integers \$p/q=x\$ instead of a native fraction and without an explicit ceiling function:

$$\lceil q/p\rceil=\begin{cases}
q/p,&q\equiv 0\pmod p\\
(q+p-(q \bmod p))/p,&q\not\equiv 0\pmod p\end{cases}$$

We have:

$$f(2\lceil1/x\rceil-1-1/x)=f(2\lceil q/p\rceil-p/p-q/p)$$

which is turned into the following JS code:

```javascript
f(q % p ? q + p - q % p * 2 : q - p, p)
```

which can be further simplified to:

```javascript
f(q + p - (q % p || p) * 2, p)
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

Expects a pair of integers `(p,q)` representing the fraction \$p/q\$.

```javascript
f=(p,q)=>p-q?p>q?f(p-q,p)+1:2*f(p,q-p):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctRCoAgEATQ/07i1hqYhSBUZ4nKKETXiq5v9Zv9DW9mtuEajnFf6eTOT3OMpmWEAdqOeOipC71hT0KCQugqN2/JCbSIo3eHt3Np/cIMEygAsq/JxOofk1gn1kiUKl0qbJ5/vAE)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (p, q) =>   // (p, q) = input pair
p - q ?         // if p is not equal to q:
  p > q ?       //   if p is greater than q:
                //     we're located on the right branch
    f(p - q, p) //     turn it into the corresponding left branch
    + 1         //     and add 1
  :             //   else:
                //     we're located on the left branch
    2 *         //     double the result of
    f(p, q - p) //     a recursive call with the parent fraction
:               // else:
                //   we've reached the root
  1             //   stop and return 1
```

Answer (score 13):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 29 bytes

```
f(x)=if(x,1+f(-1\-x*2-1-1/x))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWe9M0KjRtM4GkjqF2moauYYxuhZaRrqGuoX6FpiZEzU2nxIKCnEqNCgVdO4WCosy8EiBTCcRRUgBp19RRiDbUUTDUN9ZRMAERxvomOgqmxvrG5kC2ub6pcSzUJJitAA)

\$\begin{align}f(0)&=0\\f(x)&=1+f(2\lceil1/x\rceil-1-1/x)\end{align}\$

Comment: How the hell does this even work?? Is it based on the recursive formula on Wikipedia to find the \$i\$'th term in the sequence \$q_{i+1}=\frac1{2\lfloor q_i\rfloor-q_i+1}\$?

Comment: @AidenChow Yes. \$q_{i+1}=1/(2\lfloor{q_i}\rfloor-q_i+1)\Rightarrow 1/q_{i+1}-1=\lfloor{q_i}\rfloor-(q_i-\lfloor{q_i}\rfloor)\$. \$\lfloor{q_i}\rfloor\$ is an integer and \$0\le q_i-\lfloor{q_i}\rfloor<1\$, so \$\lceil{1/q_{i+1}-1}\rceil=\lfloor{q_i}\rfloor\$, \$q_i-\lfloor{q_i}\rfloor=\lceil{1/q_{i+1}-1}\rceil-(1/q_{i+1}-1)\$. Thus \$q_i=\lfloor{q_i}\rfloor+(q_i-\lfloor{q_i}\rfloor)=\lceil{1/q_{i+1}-1}\rceil+(\lceil{1/q_{i+1}-1}\rceil-(1/q_{i+1}-1))=2\lceil{1/q_{i+1}}\rceil-1-1/q_{i+1}\$.

Comment: what the hell.... how you thinking of these things? i try convert that equation into something useful but came up short.....

Answer (score 10):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
g-¨£∨)↔vÞṘṘB
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJ+IiwiIiwiZy3CqMKj4oioKeKGlHbDnuG5mOG5mEIiLCIiLCJbMSwxXSA9PiAxXG5bMSwzXSA9PiA0XG5bNCwzXSA9PiA5XG5bMyw0XSA9PiAxNFxuWzUzLDM3XSA9PiAxMDgxXG5bMzcsNTNdID0+IDE5OTAiXQ==)

Takes input as a pair of numbers.

```
g-¨£∨)↔vÞṘṘB

             # function taking a pair and returning its parent:
g-           #   subtract minimum
  ¨£∨        #   zip and return the last truthy element from each pair
     )       # end function
      ↔      # apply until fixed point and collect intermediate results
       vÞṘ   # vectorizing is sorted in reverse?
          Ṙ  # reverse
           B # convert from binary
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 34 bytes (@Neil)

```python
f=lambda Q:Q and 1+f(1/Q-1-2/Q%-2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZC_bsMgEId3P8UJqRKk5wZiR4kjZe3uOfJA_qAiBbAOMuRZumRpX6hT36bnyEUCfffdb7jj83u8l48UH4-vW3H19le4_dWG49lCv-vBxjOYVyfNsq9NvVr2L_VKzckfRymAI3sqPsUMPoyJCrzPAmxmrmab77ni-5YvhS6nG2VOXH3wRbZaa1W5RBDRg49wOAhjBJoBGRqB7QQtQzdB03JrUlKs2YlmIxQavTVPxRVOnlXX6WHYVcDHEex5FrkIdpQ-FoxKPRsjcSUdoeNHoZ9X-_-MPw)

Port of @Arnauld's latest and greatest which ports @alephalpha's.

Expects a Python Fraction object.

##### Previous [Python](https://www.python.org), 44 bytes (@xnor)

```python
f=lambda Q:Q==1or(Q>1)+2*f(max(Q/(1-Q),Q-1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY_BasMwDEDv_Qrhk90prFoy2hTS4-4-hxy8DTFDbQfXhe5beullPfWH9jdTQqaDeHpCSLrex-_yleLt9nMuXO1-kbujC--fDuzedh2lrO2BzNPLmnVwF22fNVXWoK3ImGXmwTkF4Ow-ik_xBD6MKRd4WwS4k_CKU4aIHnyEvldECmlAgVphM0Ej0E5QN9KalFav4lS9VQZps6NZSYWTF9W2m2HYr0CCM3SyRK-DG7WPBaMxc2PMUmnOyJIM-uXm_3__AA)

##### Original [Python](https://www.python.org), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda Q:Q==1or(Q>1)+2*f([Q/(1-Q),Q-1][Q>1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY-xbgIxDEB3vsLKlFAfxdwhOKRjZM98ypBSWY3US04hDP2WLix04of6N_Whqwfr-VmW7e-f8at8pHi73a-Fq_3virtPP7y9e7AH23WUsrZHMi-bJevevmqqrEFbketFOzNPPTinATj7cwkpXiAMY8oFTrMAfxFecMoQMUCI0PeKSCE5FKgVNhM0Au0EdSOtSWm1FafqnTJI6z09lVQ4eVFtu3busAAJztDJEr0c_KhDLBiNeTbGLJXmjCzJYJhv_v_4Dw)

Expects a Python Fraction object.

Similar but as far as I can tell not identical to @Arnauld's approach.

Comment: [Selecting with `max` also seems to work.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY_BasMwDEDv_Qrhk90prFoy2hTS4-4-hxy8DTFDbQfXhe5beullPfWH9jdTQqaDeHpCSLrex-_yleLt9nMuXO1-kbujC--fDuzedh2lrO2BzNPLmnVwF22fNVXWoK3ImGXmwTkF4Ow-ik_xBD6MKRd4WwS4k_CKU4aIHnyEvldECmlAgVphM0Ej0E5QN9KalFav4lS9VQZps6NZSYWTF9W2m2HYr0CCM3SyRK-DG7WPBaMxc2PMUmnOyJIM-uXm_3__AA)

Comment: A port of @Arnauld's latest formula is at most 35 bytes: `f=lambda p,q:p and-~f(q-q%-p*2-p,p)`.

Comment: Thanks, @Neil. Using fractions I managed to shave one off.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 24 bytes

```
*`(1+%$:@-~_1+2*>.@%)@.*
```

-4, port of [@Jo King's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260512/110888), which is a port of @loopy walt's, which is a port of @Arnauld's, which is a port of @alephalpha's.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxQytBw1BbVcXKQbcu3lDbSMtOz0FV00FPCyJ9U0OTKzU5I19BR09DJ01Tzc5QwbDIWMEEiI2LTBRMjYuMzRWMzYtMjSHqFyyA0AA)

```
*`(1+%$:@-~_1+2*>.@%)@.*
                       *  NB. signum, 0 for 0, 1 for everything else
                     @.   NB. index into the gerund list and execute
*                         NB. if 0, use signum again to return 0
  (                 )     NB. if 1, execute the recursive function
                          NB. uses the formula in alephalpha's PARI/GP answer
      $:@                 NB. recurse here
```

#### Original 28 bytes

```
[:#[(1%1+]-~2*<.@])^:~:^:a:*
```

In short, returns the length of the sequence up to the input. Expects a rational number.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxJ9pKOVrDUNVQO1a3zkjLRs8hVjPOqs4qzirRSgui5KaGJldqcka-go6ehk6appqdoYJhkbGCCRAbF5komBoXGZsrGJsXmRpD1C9YAKEB)

```
[:#[(1%1+]-~2*<.@])^:~:^:a:*
                           *  NB. signum, returns 1 for all inputs to give initial value
   [                          NB. input unchanged
    (             )^:~:^:a:   NB. form for a do-while that uses a: to collect results into an array
                              NB. u^:v^:_ v is a boolean function and u modifies the initial value
                         a:   NB. empty box
                     ~:       NB. continue if input is not equal to current value
              <.@]            NB. floor the right arg (qᵢ)
            2*                NB. double
         ]-~                  NB. subtract by qᵢ
       1+                     NB. increment
     1%                       NB. reciprocal
[:                            NB. then
  #                           NB. take the length
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```raku
+*o{{1/$_-1-2/$_%-2}...0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcVNCoMwEAbQfU7xCW1RQzIZJ9Zm0ZsIpVADBf/QlYhnT6Wb9@Zu6e9p2HCLeCLpctp3psvLsKnOrqY6rLXuSOt7Q8z1kOXtRxct/csKxGlB/x27NTExWDEJvPKnQQl5sFe1kDRg92AlDdUCDsH9AA)

Port of [@loopy walt's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260477/76162), which is a port of @Arnauld's, which is a port of @alephalpha's.

Answer (score 5):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 49 bytes

```arturo
f:$[p q][(p=q)?->1->(p>q)?->1+f p-q p->2*f p q-p]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?z0ch2i)

Port of Arnauld's [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260473/97916).

Answer (score 5):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), <del>91</del> <del>84</del> <del>81</del> 77 bytes

Based on the recursive relation:

$$ a_n = b_{n-1} $$
$$ b_n = 2\cdot b_{n-1} \cdot \left \lfloor \frac{a_{n-1}}{b_{n-1}} \right \rfloor - a_{n-1} + b_{n-1}$$

0-indexed. Recursion is very verbose in rust so I hope this is shorter than the recursive version most other answers use.

```rust
|m|{let mut d=(1,1,1);while(d.0,d.1)!=m{d=(d.1,d.0+d.1-d.0%d.1*2,d.2+1)};d.2}
```

- -7 bytes thanks to [AlephaAlpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260472/find-index-of-rational-number-in-calkin-wilf-sequence/260488#comment573282_260488)
- -4 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260472/find-index-of-rational-number-in-calkin-wilf-sequence/260488?noredirect=1#comment573300_260488)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY5RbsIwDIbfcwqDhBaPFJF2G4iq7AScYJomRBMtUpuhNhUSIdfgZS99GIfiNjNQSqzk-_3Hsv37VzW1a89P2kK5NpYj-EI50AvQlnPz9iLoIkbLpjZ7lZ0ap6P5eXUoD9e6snGQZ1wKCkx336ZQPJ9MRT6ROMhKT38kKZ2OiRFxRHyOyYnHEkNKDF3TY8qY_qnAqdp9bda1AmPhgwEdLi-bXB4UNyOmeZ2UInnI-C4T0dcmM_GaIPsEf823lbGusAM-9P2oxXsAH4YCNO89xJQF1m3Xtjf-Aw)

Comment: `if*n==m{None}else{...;Some(0)}` => `(*n!=m).then(||{...;0})`

Comment: `d.0+d.1-d.0%d.1*2` is a shorter formula (`a(n) = a(n-2) + a(n-1) - 2*(a(n-2) mod a(n-1))` from OEIS A002487).

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Uses [AndrovT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/116074/androvt)'s method from their [Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260476/53748), go upvote!

```
_ṂoƊƬ</€¬ṚḄ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a pair of co-prime positive integers, `[numerator, denominator]` and yields the 1-indexed index of that fraction in

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@4c6m/GNdx9bY6D9qWnNozcOdsx7uaPl/dNLDnTN0DrdnPWqYo2Brp/CoYa5m5P//0dGGOgqGsTpcCiCGMZhhAmMY6yiYgBmmQJaxOUTMXEfB1Dg2FgA)**

#### How?

```
_ṂoƊƬ</€¬ṚḄ - Link: pair of positive, coprime integers, [N,D]
    Ƭ       - start with C=[N,D] and collect until a fixed-point applying:
   Ɗ        -   last three links as a monad - f([N,D]):
 Ṃ          -     minimum ([N,D])
_           -     ([N,D]) subtract (that) (vectorises)   -> [0,D-N] or [N-D,0]
  o         -     (that) logical OR ([N,D]) (vectorises) -> [N,D-N] or [N-D,D]
       €    - for each ([numerator, denominator] pair in the collected results):
      /     -   reduce by:
     <      -     is (the numerator) less than (the denominator)?
        ¬   - logical NOT (vectorises)
         Ṛ  - reverse
          Ḅ - convert from binary
```

---

Loads of \$11\$s, is there a \$10\$?

e.g.:

```
_ṂoƊƬṚUṢƑ€Ḅ
_ṂoƊƬṚZ</¬Ḅ
_ṂoƊƬIF<1ṚḄ
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>59</s> 53 bytes

*Thanks [@Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for -6 bytes and fixing the floating point issue*

```
0+0.
N+X:-A is 2*ceiling(1/N)-1-1rdiv N,A+B,X is B+1.
```

Took the recursive formula from [@alephalpha's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260482/96039), so make sure to upvote his answer as well!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcy7CoQwEAXQfr9isEo2E9cYRbAQ4gdYB8RC9iEBH0Flt/PXsw@MxRYDl3sPY@epnzq@vIxzEYvCU8V0zhWYBeLz9W56M3ZEXCrKBRfzzTyhQsVK1F9RMhG6nA@t7c2yklo1RUEU0/iY5qFdSbBZ4AVsdhsDrBXqhlKsBQr4fYox9lGiPLqj8WOCyZ9KMfVcegPpHmWGn9uhbGjo3g)

Comment: You can avoid the float inaccuracies by passing in rational numbers, e.g. [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY69CoMwFIX3PkVwSpob6426OATiAzgHxEH6IwF/gpF289VTlOrQ7Z7vfByum6d@6oT/2BASnsSXiptCaGI9kdf70/Z27CjeKiZQ4Pywb1KB5iWYzSg5xqEQQ@t66xda60YpqrmB1zQP7UKj1RGhyOrWMYJag2kYgxoByb4kQR5nCunJTnKUGWR/Vg75of9I1jDYv94SRZAsDl8). In updated versions of Prolog SWI, you can do `1r2` to represent a rational number

Comment: @JoKing Huh, thanks for the info! I didn't realize `rdiv` was a thing...

Comment: Huh, also didn't realize that putting the `0+0.` case on its own would work... usually when i do that the `N` isn't evaluated or smth and the code doesn't work, so I now just put everything in one line so that the `N<(number)` would evaluate the `N` without me having to worry about anything. I guess it just works in this case...

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>34</s> 24 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＷθ«≦⁻⁻η⊗﹪η±θθ≔ιη→»Ｉⅈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw/C8IwFMTn9lO88RXiVESwk@gimCJOrmn7bAIxqflTB/Gzx1QXbzl@d9z1UrjeCp3S0UwxtPHekcNH1ZT/LDM/pdIEuYJXWXAx7bxXoznRLSBXJnoGX0PJ4GBjp2lAboeo7ZK0NIpAeZzFYLkvfntUDJb3gtuZcHtRowwZ3@XZKRNwL3zAK1ZVk9K6hnqTVrP@AA) Link is to verbose version of code. 1-indexed. Takes input as two integers. Explanation: Port of @Arnauld's port of @alephalpha's answer.

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the numerator and denominator.

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat until the numerator is zero.

```
≦⁻⁻η⊗﹪η±θθ
```

Calculate the next numerator. This uses true modulus, so instead of writing `q + p - (q % p || p)` I can write `q - q % -p`; the final expression is then `q - q % -p * 2 - p`.

```
≔ιη
```

Save the copy of the numerator that conveniently happens to be in the loop variable to the denominator.

```
→
```

Increment the count.

```
»Ｉⅈ
```

Output the final count.

Previous 34-byte version based on @AndrovT's answer:

```
≔Ｅ²ＮθＷ↨θ±¹«⊞υ‹ι⁰ＵＭθ∨⁻κ⌊θκ»⊞υ¹Ｉ↨⮌υ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BDoIwFETXcIq//E1qIhDjgpWyMhEk3qBiAw20QD/FhfHstcS4mplk5k3TCduMYvD@RKRag6WYMOVwMZNbKqcf0iJjHGaWx69ODRLwLEjizKGSrVgkJowxeMdR7ahDx@EqiVBx2LMwiQKuGLUW5rlNbhZLZRxhzyEYpZ3GecP3W/kT/xlJSLVVZsFC0PJ7vMtV2qAu1NPwmXt/yCA7@t06fAE) Link is to verbose version of code. 1-indexed. Takes input as two integers. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅ²Ｎθ
```

Input the fraction.

```
Ｗ↨θ±¹«
```

Repeat until the numerator and denominator are equal.

```
⊞υ‹ι⁰
```

If the numerator was larger than push a `1` bit otherwise push a `0` bit.

```
ＵＭθ∨⁻κ⌊θκ»
```

Subtract the smaller element from the larger.

```
⊞υ¹
```

Push a final `1` bit.

```
Ｉ↨⮌υ²
```

Convert from base `2`.

I could have done better by generating the sequence (<s>36</s> 33 bytes):

```
≔⮌Ｅ²ＮθＦ²⊞υ¹Ｗ¬⁼θυ«≔⁺⁻Συ⊗﹪⊟υυυυ→»Ｉⅈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU49C8IwFJybX/HGF4iDigh2EnVwqBRdXFONTSA2bZJXB/G3x/ixHHcH93HR0l@ctCmtQzBth0c1Kh8UVrLHmYB911M80L1RHjnnAgZespvzgDMONQWNJGCavYc2VgEeXMTdQNIGHARQjsCTFf/u2lLAynQZT3RHynVbR41VV6zclazD2vVfm75bP1ayonKjwtXRtDpm@WK1N13EjQwRz59bZUqLOcyXaTLaNw) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Takes input as two integers. Explanation:

```
≔⮌Ｅ²Ｎθ
```

Input the fraction in reverse.

```
Ｆ²⊞υ¹
```

Start with `1` as the fraction.

```
Ｗ¬⁼θυ«
```

Repeat until the fraction is found.

```
≔⁺⁻Συ⊗﹪⊟υυυυ
```

Find the next fraction. (And yes, that is legitimately `4` `υ`s in a row.)

```
→
```

Increment the loop count.

```
»Ｉⅈ
```

Output the final count.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 72 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxCsIwEIb3PsW55TQFYyqFQgVHBydxEodY2xKpMUmzSOmzx6Ru1ht@7vv47/pKdMK/bo@6cnAUUsGQANzrBp4BiLBtX8DeWvG@nJyVqr1iAWclHZQw@NhriC4OylETE2OUMrjULMo1xm1ncGKqccWg7voaNstgqEk1Tsg8hNHhvesUaQijDDH5dXzmsj@O02zmtpzyfN7M6fZ7Pyaj/wA)

```scala
def f(p:Int,q:Int):Int=if(p-q!=0)if(p>q)f(p-q,p)+1 else 2*f(p,q-p)else 1
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@xDoIwEIb3PsXv1mpNRDAkJJg4OjgZJ@NQkRIM1gJdjOHZEUpADbrc5b77/mtaRiITdX0/X@PIYCdShScBLrHErRmoKJIywKYoxOO4N0WqkhMLcFCpQWjNzpVUB9gqw5HbzmwdFCCVoBpz5JiEWLCB95s18k@I9mKrc2iGGZxhUyHOyvhLXWLa6s3bTUKzt0r@RPprnVAR23TzOZMpKqnDHcZGzB0x7wdzuTdiK5e7/tj0@arLV6Sq6xc)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def f(p: Int, q: Int): Int = {
      if (p - q != 0) {
        if (p > q) {
          f(p - q, p) + 1
        } else {
          2 * f(p, q - p)
        }
      } else {
        1
      }
    }

    println(f(1,1))
    println(f(1,3))
    println(f(4,3))
    println(f(3,4))
    println(f(53,37))
    println(f(37,53))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>38</s> 28 bytes

```ruby
->m{m>0?1+f[1/m-1-2/m%-2]:0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y63OtfOwN5QOy3aUD9X11DXSD9XVdco1sqg9n@BAlCwSN8wlgvEMinSN4awjIv0TaAs8yJ9U@PY/wA)

Using @alephalpha/@Arnauld formula like most of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 36 bytes

```
ii$\l2-nao;
:?!\$&:::&+:@$:@%:?$~2*-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzNTJSbHSDcvMd@ay8peMUZFzcrKSk3bykHFykHVyl6lzkhL9/9/VVMA)

Port of [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260473/76162). Takes input as codepoints, e.g. 53/37 is `5%`

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 59 bytes

```
1ii11$4[:{:{:{:\
@=r@={+2(?v]{n;\
*-+{1+}40.\r{]$:@$:@$:@%2
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMWlpMTEkNFs6ezp7Ons6XFxcbkA9ckA9eysyKD92XXtuO1xcXG4qLSt7MSt9NDAuXFxye10kOkAkOkAkOkAlMiIsImlucHV0IjoiNTMgMzciLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIn0=)

Despite not having a easy way to check tuple equality still shorter than rust. Uses the formula [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260472/find-index-of-rational-number-in-calkin-wilf-sequence/260488?noredirect=1#comment573300_260488) suggested under my Rust answer.

### Explanation

`1ii11` pushes the initial state.

`$4[:{:{:{:@=r@={+2(?vr{]` Checks if the 2 tuples are equal

`$:@$:@$:@$2*-+` Performs the basic calculation of the next value for `B`

`{1+}` Adds one to the counter

`]{n;` Prints the result and exits, if the tuples are equal.

[image]